# Storing XML data withing winform application

Tags: xml, winforms

I am creating a WinForm application in C# using VS2005, whihc receives an XML data, that needs to be displayd in the winform fields. What is the best way to store the XML data withing winform (either by caching or by creating some tabled dataset)?

Also how to pass this stored data across various winforms withing the application? Please help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183420/automatically-create-xml

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the System.Xml.Linq.XElement class